# Function of timer's output buffer

Tags: 555, buffer

What's the function of the timer's output buffer?

[image]

Comment: Lore Gala - Hi, (a) Stack Exchange rules are that anything written in the box labeled "Your Answer" below, as you did, *must* be an answer to the original question. Therefore your "answer", despite being a polite "thank you", has been deleted. (b) Please see [here](/help/someone-answers) in the site [help] about what to do when someone answers your question. I also recommend looking at the [tour]. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As internal signals are only strong enough to drive the internal circuitry connected to them, the buffer provides strong output current drive ability for driving external circuitry.

Answer (score 2):

The function is the typical output used from the 555. It can sink or source up to 100 or 200mA to drive LEDs, perhaps a relay etc. See the [datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/LM555CM-NOPB-Texas-Instruments-datasheet-7283993.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I googled and found these.
That may help you.

The 555 timer IC can be used as an inverting buffer as well.

https://sound-au.com/articles/555-timer.htm

https://electronicsclub.info/555buffer.htm